# tab indicator size image

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I created a Android tab bar and have some troubles customizing my tab-indicator as i want. What i want is that my indicator (a selector selecting two images depending the state, the images only differ from color, not from size) is the full size of the tab and the rest of the tabbar invisible/gone/ not the squares and line.

Here is an image how it looks now (terrible):

[image]

What i want is that the indicators are full width and connect on the sides (i did not create all the different indicators, this is why it doesnt look like that is going to connect nicely).

So what i actually want is that i have five custom tabs that dont have the looks of an android tabbar, but i do want the functionality. I know i can put these buttons on the bottom of every screen but that is still not the same in handling as a tabbar.
Anyone got an idea?

This is my tabhost:

```
public class MainTabHost  extends TabActivity {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabhost);

            final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
            addTab(R.drawable.tab_chat, someActivity.class);
            addTab(R.drawable.tab_chat, someActivity.class);
            addTab(R.drawable.tab_chat, someActivity.class);
            addTab(R.drawable.tab_chat, someActivity.class);
            addTab(R.drawable.tab_chat, someActivity.class);

            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        }

        private void addTab(int drawableId, Class<?> c) {
            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
            TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab");

            spec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(drawableId));

            spec.setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
        }

    }
```

I know tabbar is deprecated now but i have my reasons, its just a small, short term project.